# Does Carbon act as a Faraday Cage?

Tags: material-science, radio

I am wondering if a GPS LTE-M tracker can be put inside carbon handlebars.

I know the answer essentially boils down to Carbon acting as a Faraday cage but could not find a satisfying answer to this.

Does Carbon block radio waves ? If yes or no, why - afaik it is not a metal ?

Comment: No. Carbon doesn’t block radio waves.

Comment: Carbon absorbs RF radiation - I would expect it to reduce the signal but not eliminate the signal - it depends on thickness, type of carbon, e.g., carbon nano tubes, etc. Also the bulk shape of the carbon material contributes to the damping of reflected signals, stray signals, etc.. But if there are any wires leading into a Faraday cage, the wires will function as antennas.

Comment: FWIW This YouTuber who regularly builds carbon fibre rockets uses fibreglass over the GPS receiver: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZQvK8EFJQzw&t=13m39s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphite is a pretty good conductor, so it should work as a Faraday cage, but I assume you would be working with carbon fiber. I don't think carbon fiber on its own conducts well enough. You could always test it.

Comment: So the better the conductor, the higher the "shielding effect" ?

Comment: Yes! The shielding effect is caused by charges inside the material being rearranged, such that the field due to the internal charges cancels out the field caused by the external signal. However, a material has to have good electrical conductivity in order for its internal charges to move around.